# How do I add a timestamp in header manually to a soap XML (WS-Security)?

Tags: xml, header, timestamp, ws-security

I'm trying to test a webservice that uses WS-Security. And I want to use cURL to test my calls.

Does anyone know how to add a timestamp in XML HEADER? The server doesn't use user+password, instead it uses the timestamp.